# Using ant task in mobilefirst error in wladm cmd

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_invoking_the_wladm_program.html

I'm trying to enter a command in cmd and tried this:

> wladm --url=http://IP:9080 --user=demo --passwordfile=PATH\wladm.config --secure=false show info

I'm getting this error:

> Error accessing http://IP:9080/userAndConfigInfo?locale=en_US:
>   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Now when I enter another command:

> wladm --url=http://IP:9080 --user=demo --passwordfile=PATH\wladm.config --secure=false list adapters RuntimeName

I'm getting this error:

> Error accessing http://sv591527.ph.sunlife:9080/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/Sun
>   lifeTestApp/adapters?pageSize=1000000000&locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the runtime really deployed? is the server.xml correctly set?

Comment: Yes the runtime is deployed. What needs to be set in server.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should contain the context root of the MobileFirst web application for administration services, that is, should be something like http://IP:9080/wladmin or http://IP:9080/worklightadmin. For more details, please consult the wladm usage documentation http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_invoking_the_wladm_program.html.